# Interacting with Already deployed Ethereum Contract and recording response

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, ropsten, web3.py

I understand this topic has been discussed before, but my question is specific to `web3.py`. How can I interact with function of already deployed ethereum contracts on Ropsten TestNet. my code runs with out any error but their is no indication on blockchain that its really worked? Please help me.
I am calling function is following way:

`response = contract_data.contructor(args)
response = contract_data.functions.my_function_name(args).call()`

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want to interact with already deployed contracts you can simply call a function that loads the contract or do it with remix. Also you can look on Ethereum Book explorers to see if any new transactions were made, or after the transactions are mined, you can call `view` functions.